# What song plays in episode 1 of One Piece when Luffy punches Alvida?

Tags: one-piece, music

I'm trying to figure out the name/title of the song that plays in episode one of One Piece that starts at the 20:00 mark, when Luffy punches Alvida. Does anyone know it?

Comment: You mean the ending?

Comment: No its not the ending. It's the song that plays when luffy punches alvida

Answer (score 3):

One Piece - Music & Song Collection 1

Track 22 - Duel!!

The track contains 2 songs (little pause at 1:03, your song begins at 1:05)

Enjoy :)

Comment: The 20:00 mark corresponds to about 2:42 into the song, to be precise.